# JWT destroy token on logout

Tags: angularjs, express, token, passport.js, mean

I'm developing a MEAN App, the problem that I have is that I want to destroy the token generated by JWT. Initially I thought that the logout function would the job:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logOut();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});
```

But now I realized that "req.logOut()" is just a passport function that doesn't do anything to the token.

I send the token from client in the header of the request, so in case the user saved the token somewhere else, when logout, the user can still have access to the app if the token is included in the request. So my questions are the following, how do I destroy the token ?, is it "stored" somewhere ? is it ever auto-destroyed ?

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any method to destroy simple JWT token. But I have a suggestion to solve your issue.

You can keep the token in DB for each session. So you can validate the client request by comparing 'token from DB' with the token in 'client request header'. While logout you can remove the token form DB. So user can't access the app after logout.